# Parallel Python install on Media Temple DV server

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, mediatemple

Plesk on the MediaTemple DV servers uses Python 2.4 for stuff, so the 2.4 install can't be replaced but someone recommended installing a separate python 2.7 install since my app runs on that. I'm new to the whole server thing, so this is new territory. My sense is that I can create a new directory for the source files and use SSH to download the files to said directory and then cd into it and install python 2.7. Then I have to figure out how to make sure Apache knows to use Python 2.7 to run the django app in question. Does this sound correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can make a system wide change to your python installation, you would have to run Apache, python and Django in the same virtual environment. If it is not possible, use [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) (instead of apache) to run the Django app in a virtualenv (in a port different from Apache's). If this app runs in a subdomain, you should consider hosting the Django app in a PAAS (Heroku, Google App Engine, etc.) which allow you to easily switch running environments.

Comment: Right. the Apache, Python and Django is the same virtualenv is the plan. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, sorted it. the important thing seemed to be to edit the etc/ld.so.conf by adding usr/local/lib, then running sbin/ldconfig, which then makes ld.so.conf look like:

```
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib
```

Donwload and then compile Python

and use make && make altinstall.